# SQLAlchemy AssociationProxy on a clean POPO?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Using a non-declarative SQLAlchemy setup, can I use an `association_proxy` without having to modify my model class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preliminary hack:

(in the module where the SQLAlchemy mapping etcetera takes place:)

```
import ModelClass
ModelClass.associationProperty = association_proxy()
mapper() #etc..
```

This works but I am not sure how reliable this is.

Comment: that will work just great, the mapper() is sticking attributes onto the class as well.